# Kohana 3 - get orm validation errors

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

```
if ($user->values($_POST)->check())
{
    $user->save();
} else {

 // How can i get the errors?

}
```

Any idea how that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$user->_validate()->errors()
```

or

```
$user->validate()->errors()
```

depending on the version you're using.

Or, you can add a method in application/classes/orm.php with this;

```
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM {

public function errors($file = 'validate', $translate = TRUE)
    {
     return $this->_validate->errors( $file, $translate );
    }

}
```

and than call errors with $user->errors() , which I find a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Ah got it...

```
if ($user->values($_POST)->check())
{
    $user->save();
} else {

 $errors = $user->validate()->errors();
}
```